# How to concatenate a string and a variable into a constant name?

Tags: php, variables, global, lang

I have a constant like define("EMPLOYEE_NAME_ID","employee"); and a variable $code = EMPLOYEE;

now i want to print like below

```
<?php echo $code.NAME_ID; ?>
```

But this prints only "EMPLOYEE_NAME_ID" and i want to print "employee". Then how to print this. The all over means is that i want to retriew variables from lang file.

Comment: If you're finding you're using constants in a dynamic way like this you may want to look at your design. There may be a better way to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A unquote string in PHP will be parsed as constant,
and if the constant is undefined,
it will treat as the string (instead of a variable)

If you dealing with constant, you can make use of [constant function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) :-

```
echo constant("{$code}_NAME_ID");
```

However, use of this function will return warning message if the constant is not defined.
There are other option like [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) you can take a look,
this is ideal for handling large amount of setting / configuration

Answer (score 2):

Better way would be to use [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function

```
echo constant($code."NAME_ID");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   define('VAR1', 'my var' );

   $var2 = 'hello';

   echo $var2.''.VAR1;  // period, two apostrophes, period

   // same as if you were doing:

   echo "some string ".$var2." some more string".VAR1;
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the two is a constant, not a variable. You were attempting to use them like [variable variables](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) (oftentimes an [`array`](http://php.net/array) should be preferred in such circumstances).

You can however achieve the same effect with constants, using the [`constant()`](http://php.net/constant) lookup function:

```
 <?php echo constant("{$code}_NAME_ID"); ?>
```

Note that you still need the extra `_` underscore for this to work, which neither your constant suffix nor `$code` contained.

Answer (score 0):

`define("EMPLOYEE_NAME_ID","employee")` is a constant so when combining it with a variable your syntax should be like this.

```
$temp = "John";

$var = EMPLOYEE_NAME_ID." : ".$temp;

echo $var; {Output : employee : john}
```